# How to insert record in KDB (KX Database)

Tags: insert, kdb

I have created one table named as `test` in KDB using following statement

```
test:([doc_id:`int$()];doc_displayid:`symbol$();doc_created_date:`date$();doc_aacess_date:`timestamp$();is_native_exist:`boolean$();file_size:`real$())
```

Now I want to insert a record in this

I've tried many ways like

> 1. insert['test; (1;`D_30;.z.d;.z.P;T;8.5)]
> 2. insert['test ([];`D_30;2018.8.8;2018.8.9T12:00:00.123;T;8.5)]
> 3. insert['test (1;`D_30;.z.d;2018.8.9T12:00:00.123;T;8.5)]
> 4. insert['test (1;`D_30;.z.d;2018.8.9T12:00:00.123;T;8.5)]
> 5. 'test insert (1;`D_30;2018.8.8;2018.7.8T12:00:00.123;T;8.5)

But it doesn't  work.

So please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your `insert` statements, please check out the [KDB datatypes wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/) for examples

1. symbol should be defined with `` ` `` (uptick) i.e.  `` `test `` , should not be `'test`
2. doc_id is defined as `int`, so you need to pass an explicit `i` .e.g. `1i`, `2i`
3. There is no `T` boolean variable defined.
4. Real should be defined with an explicit `e` at the end. (8.5e)
5. timestamp is defined as `dateDtimespan` (`D`)
6. You can use either `insert` or `upsert`. `upsert` allows you to overwrite the record for already inserted record, however, the `insert` will ensure that you always enter a unique key, otherwise, it will throw an error.

---

```
upsert[`test; (1i;`D_30;.z.d;.z.P;0b;8.5e)] 
insert[`test ;(2i;`D_30;2018.08.08;2018.08.09D12:00:00.123123123;0b;8.5e)]

doc_id| doc_displayid doc_created_date doc_aacess_date               is_native_exist file_size
------| --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | D_30          2018.08.21       2018.08.21D07:33:40.630975000 0                8.5
2     | D_30          2018.08.08       2018.08.09D12:00:00.123123123 0               8.5
```

Comment: How i make  doc_id  as auto-increment column

Comment: KDB have a hidden column `i` basically a row index column. [checkout this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207055/primary-key-generation-for-kdb-table). But if a record is deleted, it readjusts itself.

Answer (score 5):

Check the `type` of your input variables before `insert` in your test table.
Basically:

- your `1` is of type long, not int;
- `2018.07.08T12:00:00.123` is of type datetime, not timestamp;
- `T` does not exist, for boolean you should write `1b` for true;
- `8.5` is of type float, not real.

When converting the above to the appropriate format, the `insert` works provided that you use backtick `` `test `` not `'test`:

```
`test insert (1i;`D_30;2018.08.08;"p"$2018.07.08T12:00:00.123;1b;8.5e)


doc_id| doc_displayid doc_created_date doc_aacess_date               is_native_exist file_size
------| --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | D_30          2018.08.08       2018.07.08D12:00:00.123000000 1               8.5
```

Comment: How i make doc_id as auto-increment column –

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207055/primary-key-generation-for-kdb-table

Comment: then how i add value in specific column like SQL if i have auto increment column